# Porting read from /dev/urandom to non-Unix platform

Tags: c, random, cryptography

I need to port some software to a platform which only has the standard ANSI C runtime and some POSIX functions. The software generates random numbers for password-encrypting ZIP files by reading from `/dev/urandom`. On Windows the software generates random numbers by using `CryptGenRandom()`. Since both functions are not available on my target platform, I have to find alternatives.

I came up with this to fill `buffer` with `length` random bytes:

```
bool zip_random(zip_uint8_t *buffer, zip_uint16_t length)
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   while(length--) *buffer++ = rand() % 256;
   return true;
}
```

This does the job but since the function is used in a cryptography context, I don't know if it's a good idea to use the old `srand` and `rand` functions. That's why I'd like to ask the question whether my approach is acceptable or if there is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: [This](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) might be interesting.

Comment: Using `srand()` and `time()` for cryptography is a disaster. Doing the job properly will be hard. What is the platform?   If there really isn’t anything available, you may have to look for the EGD (entropy gathering daemon) or something similar.  Or perhaps Schneider’s Fortuna PRNG.  Don’t try to invent your own.  It won’t be random enough

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's what I feared :) Platform is AmigaOS, so not many choices here...

Comment: You will a lot of ugly work to do unless you simply purchase a hardware true random bit generator.

Comment: [Here](http://www.trng98.se/shop/product_info.php?products_id=33) for example is one that uses the serial port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand` should not be used for anything that requires actual security.

Footnote about rand from 7.22.2.1 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations
>   are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with
>   particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

Comment: The footnote has nothing to do with srand. It refers to rand.